# Populating an input table based on dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, input

I am very new to Javascript/JQuery and I am having difficulty. What I am trying to do is put a value into an input field based on two dropdown menus (a product and the currency type). Tried a whole bunch of different things but nothing seems to work quite right.

http://jsfiddle.net/uxjvE/5/

```
var cur = {
   GBP: ['£20', '£55', '£64', '£90', '£100', '£65', '£75', '£100', '£135', '£255', '£260'],
   EUR: ['€24', '€65', '€76', '€107', '€119', '€77', '€89', '€119', '€160', '€302', '€308'],
   USD:['$85', '$85', '$99', '$139', '$155', '$100', '$116', '$155', '$209', '$394', '$402']
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.visaType').change(function() {



    }).change(); 
});
```

Saw some other similar questions but was unable to get this to work right. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want the price to update when either of the `<select>` options are changed:

```
$('#visaType, #currency-choice').change(function() {    

   var currencyType = $('#currency-choice').val();
   var price = $('option:selected', '#visaType').index();

   $('#business-visa-amount').val(cur[currencyType][price]);   

}).change();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxjvE/37/)

Comment: I've used this solution on my website. Thank you. Really helped me out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var cur = {
    GBP: ['£20', '£55', '£64', '£90', '£100', '£65', '£75', '£100', '£135', '£255', '£260'],
    EUR: ['€24', '€65', '€76', '€107', '€119', '€77', '€89', '€119', '€160', '€302', '€308'],
    USD: ['$85', '$85', '$99', '$139', '$155', '$100', '$116', '$155', '$209', '$394', '$402']
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#visaType').change(function () {

        var currencyValue = $('#currency-choice').val();

        $('#business-visa-amount').val(cur[currencyValue][this.selectedIndex]);

    }).change();
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uxjvE/26/

#### Explaination

`cur[currencyValue][this.selectedIndex]`

cur is your object which holds 3 arrays GBP,USD,EUR

currencyValue will fetch me the selected currency, that means `cur[currencyValue]` is same as `cur.USD`or `cur.EUR`or `cur.GBP`.

`this.selectedIndex` will fetch me the index of selected option from 0 to (length-1) based on your selection. Now I am assuming that the same index in array is the amount that you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#visaType').change(function() { 
        var selectedoption = this.selectedIndex;
        var currency = $('#currency-choice').val();         
        $('#business-visa-amount').val( cur[currency][selectedoption]);

    });
```